# How should I recursively process a file in Haskell?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, haskell, file-handling

Basically I'm expanding a literate program in Haskell. There are two things I need to look for to expand. Here's an example file:

```
program.c.lit:
==============
Some comments in the source file that I can ignore
    <main>=
    code.. code ...
    code..
    <a> 

Some comments in the source file that I can ignore
    <a>=
    code... code...
    code..
```

In a file, I need to look at each `<some var>` and substitute it with its matching definition defined below `<some var>=`. All the lines which are indented with 4 spaces below a `<some defn>=` are included in that chunk. In the end i should have a file consisting of only `code ...` lines.

How should I approach this problem in terms of file processing, what's a good approach? I'm comfortable with recursion, less comfortable with monads.

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @gnat this seems much like a "whiteboard" problem to me. I'm asking for a design approach, not actual code.

Comment: Is the definition of a var contained in one line, to the right of the equal sign?

Comment: No, the defn is the indented chunk below <var name>=, until the next unindented portion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make a few assumptions in my answer. Feel free to correct me if one of them is incorrect:

- you are doing this as an exercise
- you only want to inline the top level definitions
- there is at most only one definition for a given variable name
- you want to simplify a given definition by inlining all known variables

If you are doing this for a "real" project, or want to make more complex transformations, I recommend that you look at existing packages such as [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts).

Now if you want a robust solution, you will need those functions:

```
parse 
    :: String        -- the input text
    -> [Declaration] -- a datastructure representing the expression
inline
    :: Declaration   -- the definition to inline
    -> Declaration   -- the definition to modify
    -> Declaration   -- the result definition
showDecl :: Declaration -> String
simplify 
    :: String        -- the input text
    -> String        -- the variable name to simplify
    -> String        -- the result
```

Declaration can be as simple as  `(String, String)` (the variable name and its definition). Note that I am using loosely typed definitions. I am also using String, which may not be the most efficient solution. You may consider using Text to speed things up.

The parse function can be tricky. I recommend using the parsec library. It uses a monad, but don't feel intimidated by it. Using monads does not require understanding them at a fundamental level. Actually the opposite is true. See [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) for an introduction. You can view the parsec type as a statement which consume a piece of text and maybe return some result.

```
parse input = /case analysis of / runParser (many parseBlock) () "source name" input

parseBlock = do
    skipComment
    parseDef

parseDef = do
    varName <- parseVar
    string " = "
    definition <- parseExpr
    return $ Declaration varName defintion

parseExpr = ...
```

Here, unit tests are your best friends. Be sure that all your smaller parsers are working well before combining them. Pay attention to the backtracking semantics (ie the `try` combinator) because you can easily shoot yourself in the foot with that.

The inline function is easier. It will just be a well thought out search and replace. The simplify function is just a matter of calling `parse`, extracting the declaration to simplify, and calling `inline` with all the other ones on it. No recursion needed.

Alternatively, your `inline` function can be of type `Declaration -> String -> String`, and edit directly the input string. This way you won't have to write the `showDecl` function.

Comment: There can be multiple extensions of a chunk. By using the same name with the `<>=` syntax. This is exactly the help I was looking for, thank you.